# Connect 2 monitors to the HDMI output to extend your screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a notebook (HP 250 G9), with an HDMI output, to which an external monitor is already connected.

I would like to understand if, through a splitter, or any other solution, whether it's a cable or a box, or another attack, it is possible to connect at least one other monitor, **to extend the desktop (not clone)**, for a total of 3 monitors (the notebook one and 2 external ones).

I know that this could be possible using an external video card, connecting it either to a thunderbolt port (which I don't have) or to a PCIe slot on the motherboard (a bit complicated, I would have to give up either the M2 SSD or the WIFI card), so **I would like to avoid this solution**.

Thanks

Comment: `to extend the desktop (not clone)` - no - does your device have usb 3.0?

Comment: yes of course, USB  3.2 Type A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI splitters are "illegal" devices. As such, they can *sometimes* clone the image to another display, but that's it.

Unlike DisplayPort, HDMI does not support Daisy-Chaining.

If you laptop does not have Thunderbolt or a USB-C port that supports DisplayPort Alt Mode, you only have one option left: A DisplayLink USB graphics adapter. They are suitable for office work and video playback, but not for gaming. DisplayLink technology is built into many devices, including some so-called "universal docking stations".

---

Technically you could also use a HMDI-to-DisplayPort active converter and a Matrox DualHead2Go or TripleHead2Go device. This would however be very costly and will come with its own set of limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't have to use it for gaming, just office and some videos.
I realized I didn't specify that I'm a Linux user, do these 2 solutions work on Ubuntu? Thank you

Comment: Hm, probably… not so good? [DisplayLink _does_ offer Ubuntu drivers](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0), but I do not have any experience with them.

Comment: I've visited that site, maybe I'll wait for some ubuntu user to answer me or I'll ask another question. Thanks again